# Get a certain number of elements into an Array

Tags: c, arrays, int

This is my code so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define SIZE 200

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

FILE * ifp = NULL;
int inputArray[SIZE];
int i, j;
int c;

ifp = fopen("testfile.txt", "r");

for (i = 0; i <= SIZE; ++i)
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &inputArray[i]);
/*fscanf(ifp, "%d", */

for (i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)
    printf("%d", inputArray[i]);
return 0;


}
```

So I have a file that has nnumbers in it like:
3
5 5 3
6
3 2 6 4 1 1

The code above seems to work in getting the numbers into an array like 3 5 5 3 6 3 2...etc.
But then, the array size is 200. So the rest of the space not used in the array isn't just blank. It has a huge, weird numbers in it
so when I print it out, it it prints 
35536326411 -858993460 -858993460
it prints that -858993460 to what I assume is about 200 times.

I'm a total noob in C and in programming. I asked the professor about the array size and he said just set it to a large number like 100 or 200 because trying to set the size of the array to a variable that can be changed (or something to that concept) is complicating and isn't at our level quite yet.

I need to do math with these numbers and I don't want to include those -858993460 things in my calculations. How would I determine where in the array is the last element that was actually declared? 
Someone please point me into the right direction...

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i <= SIZE; ++i)
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
```

Else you have array out of bound access which will lead to undefined behavior.

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
  if(fscanf(ifp, "%d", &inputArray[i]) != 1)
  break;
}
```

Set all elements to 0 using

```
memset(array,0,sizeof(array));
```

Comment: Would there be any other way that brings a similar result?

Comment: @bhroask Else you can set the whole array to `0` using `memset(array,0,sizeof(array)`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the return value of `fscanf()` and once it returns failure [return `!=1`], you should stop scanning anymore.

Further, you can use that `i-1` value for printing *valid* elements.

Also, you should change your loop limit to `i < SIZE` to avoid off-by-one error.

Then, you can initialize the local variables to avoid them having garbage values. You can use `memeset()` or initializer-lists to get that part done.

Answer (score 0):

Don't define SIZE, make it a variable that will contains real count of number in file after reading.

```
size_t SIZE = 0;
for (SIZE = 0; ; ++SIZE)
{
    if (fscanf(ifp, "%d", &inputArray[i]) == EOF)
        break;
}
```